# mysql - filtering a list against keywords, both list and keywords > 20 million records (slow)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, both having more than 20 million records; table1 is a list of terms, and table2 is a list of keywords that may or may not appear in those terms.  I need to identify the terms that contain a keyword.
The 'term' field is a VARCHAR(320) and the 'keyword' field is a VARCHAR(64).

My current strategy is:

```
SELECT table1.term, table2.keyword FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.term 
LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.keyword, '%');
```

This is not working, it takes  f o r e v e r.
It's not the server, afaict (see notes).

How might I rewrite this so that it runs in under a day?

I have entertained in-memory tables, or changing to innodb and making the buffer pool big enough to hold both tables.  Unfortunately, each mysql thread is bound to one cpu, but I have 4 cores (well, "8" with hyperthreading); if I could distribute the workload, that would be fantastic.

Notes:

1. Regarding server optimization: both tables are myisam and have unique indexes on the matching fields; the myisam key buffer is greater than the sum of both index file sizes, and it is not even being fully taxed (`key_blocks_unused` is ... large); the server is a 2x dual core xeon 2U beast with fast sas drives and 8G of ram, tuned for the mysql workload.
2. I just remembered that I only index the first 80 characters of the 'term' field (to save disk space); not sure if this is hurting or helping.
3. MySQL 5.0.32, Debian Lenny x86_64

Comment: The index on term will not get used in a LIKE query like yours, so it doesn't matter. Because you are essentially going through every keyword, index on that doesn't matter either.

Comment: Would a regular expression be faster than LIKE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set up a full-text index, then do a search against that. Right now, your unique index probably isn't helping the search at all (because of the leading '%' in the search).

That means, it's almost certainly running a full scan of table1 for each item in table2. Calling that grossly inefficient is putting it nicely. Building a full-text index is somewhat slow (though probably faster than what you're doing right now) but once that's done, the searching should go a *lot* faster.

As to what to use to do the full-text indexing: while MySQL has a built-in full-text indexing capability, I doubt it'll help you a lot -- with 20 million rows, its performance is pretty poor (at least in my experience). [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) is a bit more work to set up, but is a lot more likely to give you adequate performance.

Comment: why fulltext for regular M:M relation?

Answer (score 1):

for first you should normalize your schema: you should make 3rd table to keep relation between `terms` and `keywords` in the manner of `term_id <-> keyword_id`, not like you doing this now - in char field separated by spaces

Comment: The problem is the initial analysis of term/keyword relationships, not their storage.  I am actually storing the results in a third table.

Comment: if you will follow my advice - you could select the data you asked fast.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, zerkms; I have set that up.  Unfortunately the initial query is *still* running (3 days now), so I still need help with that.  I am considering writing a script to perform the analysis instead, so I an have more control over parallelization etc.